# Efficiently and dynamically rank many users in memory?

Tags: performance, list, jar, java

I run a Java game server where I need to efficiently rank players in various ways.  For example, by score, money, games won, and other achievements.  This is so I can recognize the top 25 players in a given category to apply medals to those players, and dynamically update them as the rankings change.  Performance is a high priority.

Note that this cannot easily be done in the database only, as the ranks will come from different sources of data and different database tables, so my hope is to handle this all in memory, and call methods on the ranked list when a value needs to be updated.  Also, potentially many users can tie for the same rank.

For example, let's say I have a million players in the database.  A given player might earn some extra points and instantly move from 21,305th place to 23rd place, and then later drop back off the top 25 list.  I need a way to handle this efficiently.  I imagine that some kind of doubly-linked list would be used, but am unsure of how to handle quickly jumping many spots in the list without traversing it one at a time to find the correct new ranking.  The fact that players can tie complicates things a little bit, as each element in the ranked list can have multiple users.

How would you handle this in Java?

Comment: While your question is interesting, it's a rule in SO to not ask us *to **recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource*** since *they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam*.

Comment: It doesn't have to be an external resource, I'd be happy with a code example of how to use a linked list in a way that would scale up well in this scenario.

Comment: A double-linked list would not help much, since you would have to traverse the whole list in order to find the proper insertion spot. In general, a http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm comes to my mind, but without more detailed information about the underlying infrastructure, it's hard to give more specific suggestions

Comment: Do you need only the top 25 players each category or you need all the players to be in memory .

Comment: Hi @DivideByHero can you please give me the formula or code or any link that will be helpful to evaluate the rank of a player in java?. I am struggling with that. especially when the user score is between two values. Example [56699,54999] and the user score is 54888.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forget linked list. It allows fast insertions, but no efficient searching, so it's of no use.

Use the following data

```
double threshold
ArrayList<Player> top;
ArrayList<Player> others; (3)
```

and manage the following properties

- each player in `top` has a score greater or equal to `threshold`
- each player in `others` has a score lower than `threshold`
- `top` is sorted
- `top.size() >= 25`
- `top.size() < 25 + N` where `N` is some arbitrary limit (e.g., 50)

Whenever some player raises it score, do the following:

- if they're in `top`, sort `top` (*)
- if they're in `others`, check if their score promotes them to `top`
- if so, remove them from `others`, insert in `top`, and sort `top`
- if `top` grew too big, move the `n/2` worst players from `top` to `others` and update `threshold`

Whenever some player lowers it score, do the following:
- if they're in `others`, do nothing
- if they're in `top`, check if their new score allows them to stay in top
- if so, sort `top` (1)
- otherwise, demote them to bottom, and check if `top` got too small
- if so, determine an appropriate new `threshold` and move all corresponding players to `top`. (2)

(1) Sorting `top` is cheap as it's small. Moreover, [TimSort](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~martin/webrevs/openjdk7/timsort/raw_files/new/src/share/classes/java/util/TimSort.java) (i.e., the algorithm behind `Arrays.sort(Object[])`) works very well on partially sorted sequences. Instead of sorting, you can simply remember that `top` is unsorted and sort it later when needed.

(2) Determining a proper threshold can be expensive and so can be moving the players. That's why only `N/2` player get moved away from it when it grows too big. This leaves some spare players and makes this case pretty improbable assuming that players rarely lose score.

#### EDIT

For managing the objects, you also need to be able to find them in the lists. Either add a corresponding field to `Player` or use a [`TObjectIntHashMap`](http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/javadocs/gnu/trove/map/hash/TObjectIntHashMap.html).

#### EDIT 2

(3) When removing an element from the middle of `others`, simply replace the element by the last one and shorten the list by one. You can do it as the order doesn't matter and you must do it because of speed. (4)

(4) The whole `others` list needn't be actually stored anywhere. All you need is a possibility to iterate all the players not contained in `top`. This can be done by using an additional `Set` or by simply iterating though all the players and skipping those scoring above threshold.

#### FINAL RECOMMENDATIONS

- Forget the `others` list (unless I'm overlooking something, you won't need it).
- I guess you will need no `TObjectIntHashMap` either.
- Use a list `top` and a boolean `isTopSorted`, which gets cleared whenever a top score changes or a player gets promoted to `top` (simple condition: `oldScore >= threshold | newScore >= threshold`).
- For handling ties, make `top` contain at least 25 *differently scored* players. You can check this condition easily when printing the top players.

Comment: if he need only the top 25 players why do we need "others" list ? . if the "others" provided to get the rank for players (like 121th rank) how are you gonna manage the sort in million players ?

Comment: I think I understand this and I really appreciate the thorough answer!  Would you account for the possibility of ties by turning this into a two-dimensional structure, such as a List-of-Lists, or would you handle ties in another way?

Comment: @Mani: The `others` list doesn't need to be sorted. It can't be used to get players' rank. Actually, it doesn't need to exist at all, see my edit. It was just a leftover of my original idea "partition the players set into top and others".

Comment: @ZenBlender: No 2D arrays as there'd no simple way to manage it. A plain sorted list, just a bit longer so that it contains enough unique scores must do (assuming ties aren't too abundant). See my edit.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether there is library that may help you, but I think you can maintain a minimum heap in the memory. When a player's point updates, you can compare this to the root of the heap, if less than,do nothing.else adjust the heap.

**That means, you can maintain a minimum heap that has 25 nodes which are the highest 25 of all the players in one category.**

Answer (score 0):

I assume you may use plenty of memory to do that or memory is not a concern for you. Now as you want only the top 25 entries for any category, I would suggest the following:

Have a HashSet of Player objects.  Player objects have the info like name, games won, money etc.

Now have a HashMap of category name vs TreeSet of top 25 player objects in that category. The category name may be a checksum of some columns say gamewon, money, achievent etc.

```
HashMap<String /*for category name */, TreeSet /*Sort based on the criteria */> ......
```

Whenever you update a player object, you update the common HashSet first and then check if the player object is a candidate for top 25 entries in any of the categories. If it is a candidate, some player object unfortunately may lose their ranking and hence may get kicked out of the corresponding treeset.
**>> if you make the TreeSet sorted by the score, it'll break whenever the score changes (and the player will not be found in it**

Correct. Now I got the point :) . So, I will do the following to mitigate the problem. The player object will have a field that indicate whether it is already in some categories, basically a set of categories it is already in. While updating a player object, we have to check if the player is already in some categories, if it is in some categories already, we will rearrange the corresponding treeset first;  i.e. remove the player object and readjust the score and add it back to the treeset.  Whenever a player object is kicked out of a category, we remove the category from the field which is holding a set of categories the player is in

Now, what you do if the look-up is done with a brand new search criteria (means the top 25 is not computed for this criteria already) ?  ------
Traverse the HashMap and build the top entries for this category from "scratch".  This will be expensive operation, just like indexing something afresh.

Comment: If you make the `TreeSet` sorted by the score, it'll break whenever the score changes (and the player will not be found in it).

Comment: I was also thinking about a `TreeSet` but abandoned it: When a player moves from the 21305th place to 20123th, then I don't want to do anything but a trivial check quickly saying "forget it".